# Unexpected token error on returning an object from map function - reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-native

I am trying to return a dictionary/object from `map` function on an array of objects.

But Getting `Unexpected token`, I have tied tracing it, can anyone help, in which place I am wrong ?

My code sample is

```
class App extends Component {


  render() {

    let a = [
    {
      "a": 123,
      "b": "99",
    }, {
      "a": 333,
      "b": "33",
    }
  ];

  a.map((value, key) => {
    return {`${key-text}`: value["a"]};
  });

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <p>
            Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
          </p>
          <a
            className="App-link"
            href="https://reactjs.org"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            Learn React
          </a>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In above code  for line `return {`${key-text}`: value["a"]};` its showing unexpected token, what is the fault here ?

Comment: second paramter of map function is index, and there is no such thing as key-text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your map function `key-text` is actually looking for a variable called `key-text` which doesn't exists and hence the error. If you are trying to interpolate `text` to `key`, changing it to this should work

```
a.map((value, key) => {
  return {[`${key}-text`]: value["a"]};
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need a parent object to create dynamic keys.

```js
let a = [
    {
      "a": 123,
      "b": "99",
    }, {
      "a": 333,
      "b": "33",
    }
  ];

  a.map((value, key) => {
    let x = {};
    x[key+"-text"] = value["a"];
    console.log(x);
    return x;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The fault is in

```
a.map((value, key) => {
    return {`${key-text}`: value["a"]};
});
```

replace with

```
a.map((value, index) => {
    return {`${index}`: value["a"]};
});
```

here index is reference of object in array

Answer (score 0):

Here you used `text` as a variable but didn't define it.
so you must have to define a `text` variable above the map.

`Like`

```
  const text = 0; // or whatever number you want.
  a.map((value, key) => {
    return {`${key-text}`: value["a"]};
  });
```

`OR`

you can use `text` as a `string`

`Like`

```
  a.map((value, key) => {
    return {`${key}-text}`: value["a"]};
  });
```

try both and keep which is much suitable for you.